# How to make a transparent toolbar with its content visible

Tags: android

im trying to make a transparent toolbar inside a AppBarLayout so the navigation drawer icon and Title appear like this
[Toolbar i wish to make like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaCzJ.png)

this is what i achieved but i would like to remove the borders around the tool bar. i tried removing the elevation and sitting the windowContentOverlay with @null but was not successful 
[my current achieved toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzPpf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_400sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_400sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_140sdp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />




        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/kleen_green"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"-->
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```